# Oracle SQL: Hierarchical Query to generate specific sequence

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Currently I have something like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM, '009'), TO_CHAR(L, '009')
  FROM ( SELECT L 
           FROM ( SELECT LEVEL AS L
                    FROM DUAL
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000)
          ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)
```

This query produces output like this (only first 3 rows):

```
| 001 | 138 |
| 002 | 281 |
| 003 | 177 |
```

Is there any way to get something like that (adding 10 more rows for each row adding 0-9 as last char) (Only two source rows has been expanded to save space):

```
| 0010 | 1380 |
| 0011 | 1381 |
| 0012 | 1382 |
| 0013 | 1383 |
| 0014 | 1384 |
| 0015 | 1385 |
| 0016 | 1386 |
| 0017 | 1387 |
| 0018 | 1388 |
| 0019 | 1389 |
| 0020 | 2810 |
| 0021 | 2811 |
| 0022 | 2812 |
| 0023 | 2813 |
| 0024 | 2814 |
| 0025 | 2815 |
| 0026 | 2816 |
| 0027 | 2817 |
| 0028 | 2818 |
| 0029 | 2819 |
```

And so on... (I can write procedure, function but I want to have simple select statement)

Comment: `Bob's Jarvis's` and `the_silk's` solutions are correct and I used te less cost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MISTAKE POINTED OUT BY WBAR. THANKS!

```
SELECT  r || L2, l || L2
FROM
(
        SELECT TO_CHAR(ROWNUM, '009') r, TO_CHAR(L, '009') l
        FROM
        (
                SELECT L
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT  LEVEL AS L
                    FROM    DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000
                )
                ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
        )
)
CROSS JOIN
(
        SELECT  LEVEL -1 AS L2
        FROM    DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 11
)
ORDER   BY
        1, 2;
/*
 0010    8460
 0011    8461
 0012    8462
 0013    8463
 0014    8464
 0015    8465
 0016    8466
 0017    8467
 0018    8468
 0019    8469
*/
```

Comment: Not exactly correct.. first row should be something like that: `0010`, `0011`, `0012` and so on.. that means that for source `001` it should generate `0010`, `0011`, `0012`, `0013`, `0014` and so on..

Comment: Both solutions are correct but yours have less cost but `Bob's JArvis's` colution is very interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to do what you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((R*10)+((ROWVAL/10-TRUNC(ROWVAL/10))*10), '0009') AS ROW_IDX,
       TO_CHAR(ROWVAL, '0009') AS ROW_VAL
  FROM (SELECT R, L*10     AS L10,
                  (L*10)+1 AS L11,
                  (L*10)+2 AS L12,
                  (L*10)+3 AS L13,
                  (L*10)+4 AS L14,
                  (L*10)+5 AS L15,
                  (L*10)+6 AS L16,
                  (L*10)+7 AS L17,
                  (L*10)+8 AS L18,
                  (L*10)+9 AS L19
          FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS R, L
                  FROM (SELECT L 
                          FROM (SELECT LEVEL AS L
                                   FROM DUAL
                                   CONNECT BY LEVEL < 1000)
                          ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)))
  UNPIVOT (ROWVAL FOR LVL IN (L10, L11, L12, L13, L14,
                              L15, L16, L17, L18, L19));
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: GREAT!  THX! WOW You have just show me pivoting feature in 11g !  THATS amazing feature !

Comment: the solution provided by `the_slk` has less cost so thats the only reason I accepted his solution